# Sort property is omitted from the column state in Aggrid

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to get the column state whenever the sortchanged is called from aggrid

But I am only able to see the following property. I am not sure what is the reason.

```
var colState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
<==Property==>
aggFunc: null
colId: "Name"
hide: false
pinned: null
pivotIndex: null
rowGroupIndex: null
width: 200
```

I am getting the sortmodel using gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
But it is not returning sortIndex. Is there any alternative way to get the sortIndex and I would like to know why am I getting very few properties when I do gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState().
I should suppose to get following properties based on documentation

[Aggrid ColumnState documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/column-state/)

Please suggest if anyone have any workaround for this.

Found something after debugging. Some of the property(Sort etc..) are being omitted from column state. Please open the attached image.

[image: Screenshot of ag-grid-enterprise.js]

> AG-Grid Ver:ag-grid-enterprise-21.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version I was using. I tried with 25.0.1. Now it is working fine.